# instantly update info, but only if changes are made in the database swift/firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have a place to show news, located in one of the 4 tab views. For changing the information, all the aspects related to it are stored in firestore (title, subtitle, text). Currently, I'm using `addSnapshotListener` to fetch the data, because whenever I change the data in firestore it will automatically and instantly update. However, each time the user clicks on the tabview icon related to the news view, a different call to read data is done. I understand that it would cause lots of readings when the user base grow, causing a higher monthly payment to firebase and maybe delay, right? To fix this, the only solution I think about is changing `addSnapshotListener` to `getDocuments`. But, if I do any changes on firestore, the user would need to close the app and then open it to see the updated info.
Is there a way to update instantly the info, but only if changes are made in the database?

This is how I get the information from Firestore:

```
struct Info: Identifiable{
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var title: String
var subtitle: String
}



class InfoViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
@Published var infos = [Info]()
func fetchData(){
    Firestore.firestore().collection("infos").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return}
        self.infos = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Info? in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
           if let title = data["title"] as? String,
              let subtitle = data["subtitle"] as? String{
            print("info successful")
            return Info(title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
           }
           else{
            print("info failed")
            return nil
           }
        }
    }
  }

  }
```

In the view I want to display the info, I have `@ObservedObject var infoModel = InfoViewModel()`, a `ForEach` to display the data and then `.onAppear(){self.infoModel.fetchData()}`

Each time I change to this view when clicking the tabView icon, I get, on debug, 3x "info successful, as I have 3 documents stored on infos collection.

TabBar View:

```
struct TabBar: View{

@State var current = 0
@StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
var body: some View{
    NavigationView{
    TabView(selection: $current) {
        
        HomeView()
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("início")
            }
        SearchView(LocationModel: LocationModel)
            .tag(1)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Text("buscar")
            }
        CalendarView()
            .tag(2)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text("histórico")
            }
        AccountView()
            .tag(3)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (self.current == 3 ? "person.fill" : "person"))
                Text("perfil")
            }
  
    }.accentColor(Color("Color"))
}
  }
  }
```

Where firestorm data is displayed:

```
struct HomeView: View{

@StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
@StateObject var model = ModelData()
@ObservedObject var infoModel = InfoViewModel()


var body: some View{
 
            VStack( spacing: 12) {
                  
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                       HStack(spacing: 15){
                           ForEach(infoModel.infos){ info in
                           HStack(spacing: 20){
                           Text(info.title)
                           .frame(height: 220)
                           .frame(width: 330)
                               .background(Color.yellow)
                          .cornerRadius(18)
                           }
                       }
                                              
                       }.padding(.horizontal, 15)
                       .padding(.bottom, 25)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                .navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)

         .onAppear(perform: {
            LocationModel.locationManager.delegate = LocationModel
         
            self.infoModel.fetchData()
              })
            
         .alert(isPresented: $LocationModel.alert, content: {
             
            Alert(title: Text("Mensagem"), message: Text(LocationModel.alertMsg), dismissButton: .destructive(Text("Pronto").foregroundColor(Color.blue)))
         })
     }
    
   }
```

Comment: You need separation of ui (VC) and data "service", which can be a `addSnapshotListener` and preserve data for VC to display

Comment: @KirilS. Hey, thank you for replying. I'm kind of new to Firebase/Swift, so if you have any links to information that could help my I would be grateful.

Comment: For example: https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/

Comment: This kind of question is very hard to answer as it contains not code so we don't know the use case. For example this `a different call to read data is done` - we don't know what 'a different call' is or does. We also don't know if there's an issue with other code as well. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The Question is also unclear so maybe you can clarify it?

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you for the feedback. Just added code information

Comment: @Jay what I tried to say in `a different call to read data is done` was: in my current code, when I go to other tabView icon view (other than the news one), it looks like the code "forgets" it has already gotten the data stored in firestore, as if in each time I leave news view it deletes the data, and when I came back it reads it again.

Comment: Again, there's not enough information to understand the use case. Does each tab have a separate viewController or are they sharing one? Is the dataSource shared between the viewControllers if theres more than one or does each have it's own? Is the tabView a subclass that contains the dataSource? See - without knowing how and when Firebase is being read we are just guessing and any answer could send you off in the totally wrong direction. It sounds like your viewControllers which contains the dataSource are going out of scope but it's really unclear at this point.

Comment: @Jay Just added the code.

Comment: Ok, so now clarify the question; what specifically are you having issues with? It sounds like your dataSource `self.infos` is being populated and you have a `.addSnapshotListener` so if the data changes in Firestore, you'll be notified. If you want to handle specific changes within Firestore check out the Getting Started Guide [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Comment: @Jay it’s not actually an issue. I just want to confirm or not if, in my current code, each time I leave HomeView() and came back the code reads the data again. If it do read the data again, if there’s any way to make it read only if changes are made.

Comment: Again, the question is a bit vague as we don't know your code or Firestore stucture. For example, if there was a main viewController where each tab had a sub-viewController, that main VC could contains the dataSource arrays used by the sub VC's. If data in firebase changes, the main VC is notified and can update the associated dataSource with the new data. That way, each sub VC doesn't have to re-read Firebase each time as the data is always fresh in the main VC and each sub VC just has to refresh it's tableView. Also, what's the issue with each VC reading the data again?

Answer (score 1):

Your VC could have a reference to a controller that manages all communication with the Firestore. In that controller, you can init the snapshot listener. That will fetch all your documents once, which you can store as state in that controller. Any .added, .modified and .removed [document changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) from that point on can just change the state your controller is holding and update the VC with e.g. a closure.

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. I'm kind of new to Firebase/Swift, so if you have any links to information that could help my I would be grateful.